# How Can I Force IE to Make Joomla Article Images Responsive?

Tags: css, joomla, internet-explorer-11, responsive-images

http://dfwcgi.com/approach/white-papers
Live site, but neglected to trouble-shoot with IE before hand. All the article images (via images and links tab) are NOT responsive with IE11. Images in the body of any article do comply and are responsive. I've seen this "auto \9" on different forums, but cannot really find a solution. I've changed my custom css a few times but with no results. IT's a Rocket Theme. I've even created an IE11 custom css page...with no luck.

Would really appreciate input- this is driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of small changes you can make to improve the layout in Internet Explorer 11. For starters, you'll want to remove the `width: 100%` property on the DFW logo at the top of the page. Given its wide host container, this results in the image being stretched out too large:

[image]

While removing the `width: 100%` property resolves the DFW logo issue, it results in broken body images. At this point we see that the `div.pull-left.item-image` elements are actually wider than their host `<article>` elements. As such, we can apply the `max-width: 100%` property to them:

```
.pull-left { max-width: 100% }
```

This results in a restored layout in Internet Explorer 11.

[image]

Comment: I noticed FF doing the same soo I've added the max width property to my main custom css as well. This does take care of the issue with blog layouts but the item article layout is still not responsive: blog layout: http://dfwcgi.com/approach/news and item layout: http://dfwcgi.com/approach/news/120-newly-redesigned-website

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Not sure if this is THE answer, but in my master IE css page I added this:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://dfwcgi.com/templates/rt_chimera/css/master-ie11.css

This affects a few other images in the site, but was the best I could come up with for now...open for suggestions...

Thanks again!